# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in... PHP Error

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm setting up a form and I keep getting a fatal error:

> 'Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home2/ssauronn/public_html/contactusform.php on line 3'.

My PHP Form is as shown:

```
$name = $_POST ('name');

$email = $_POST ('email');

$message = $_POST ('message');

$to = "infimagine@gmail.com";

$subject = "Infimagine Contact";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);

echo "We have recieved your message and will get back to you soon!";
```

Anything you guys see wrong with it?

Comment: `$_POST['name'];`. `$_POST` - is not a function.

Comment: It should be `$_POST['']` square brackets.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array so use `[key]` subscript instead of parenthesis.

Comment: ok, thank you guys. this solved the problem!

Comment: `$_POST('name')` !== `$_POST['name'];`

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error. $_POST is an array. To get something from array, use this syntax.

```
$_POST["name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

TRy:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "infimagine@gmail.com";

$subject = "Infimagine Contact";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);

echo "We have recieved your message and will get back to you soon!";
```